# The terminal does not display Devanagri scripts (Hindi, Nepali, etc.) properly

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode, internationalization

[image]

The terminal is not combing Unicode characters correctly. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Try using **konsole** X terminal emulator.

Install using:

```
sudo apt-get install konsole
```

Here's a snapshot displaying the contents of a file containing the devnagari script:

Nepali:
[image: npsnapshot]

Hindi:
[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Terminal version 3.32 (more precisely, the underlying VTE version 0.56) addresses this issue, you should no longer see those circles.

A known issue is that the character under the solid block cursor still potentially draws such a circle. This is quite hard to fix (I'm also unsure what the exact desired behavior is). A possible workaround is to switch to I-beam or underline cursor shape.