# Miserable printing of the hindi words by python in terminal

Tags: command-line, python, language-support

Suppose I want to print मैं ठीक हुँ । in  terminal in hindi language either by using the python with unicode or if i just copy and paste, instead of correctly pasting and printins it correctly, it instead shows

[image]

this same problem happens with the punjabi, when i try to print the 'matraen' it just separates them instead of combining them, this is also happens same with python when i try to print by the unicode support of the python
like print u'\uxxxx\uxxxx', suppose the Hex numbers repents ठी but it will show ठ ी, plz help me to correct this bug.

Comment: Did you already try to set a different font in your terminal emulator?

Comment: how i dont know

Comment: I did not nothing

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/340252. (Assuming your terminal is GNOME Terminal, upgrading to version 3.32 should fix this.)